# ASP .NET Core - posting a filled in model back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on a web application that basically allows you to manage jury duty within a sports federation. One of the pages serves to assign people to a number of predefined "duties" within predefined panels. The page shows the side of the available panels (3 on a row). You can then select the panel you want to modify.

Technically, within the page, I load a partial view for each available panel. When you select a panel to edit, the page is reloaded and the selected panel is reloaded in an editable partial view.

**edit.cshtml**

```
@model Models.Database.Models.PanelOverviewModel;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Samenstelling van de panels";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h2>Samenstelling van de panels.</h2>

<div class="container-fluid  mb-3">
    <div class="container bg-light">
        @if (Model.PanelMatrix != null && Model.PanelMatrix.Count > 0)
        {
            @for (var index = 0; index < Model.PanelMatrix.Keys.Count; index++)
            {
                <div class="line"></div>

                @if (Model.PanelMatrix.ContainsKey(index))
                {
                    var panelNames = Model.PanelMatrix[index];

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        @foreach (var panel in panelNames)
                        {
                            var currentPanel = Model.PanelComposition[panel];

                            @if (currentPanel.PanelName == Model.SelectedPanel)
                            {
                                <div class="col">
                                    @await Html.PartialAsync("JuryOpstelling/_EditPanelView", currentPanel)
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="col">
                                    @await Html.PartialAsync("JuryOpstelling/_ShowPanelView", currentPanel)
                                </div>
                            }
                        }

                    </div>
                }

                <div class="line"></div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="line"></div>
            <p>Geen panels gevonden.</p>
            <div class="line"></div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**_EditPanelView.cshtml**

```
@model Models.Database.Models.PanelModel

<div class="border-right">
    <form asp-action="SavePanel" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="currentPanel" name="currentPanel" asp-for="@Model.PanelName" />
        <input type="hidden" id="wedstrijdSessie" name="wedstrijdSessie" asp-for="@Model.WedstrijdSessie" />
        <input type="hidden" id="currentMembers" name="currentMembers" asp-for="@Model.PanelComposition" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-outline-info"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <input type="button" value="Overview" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick= "location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "JuryOpsteller", new { id = Model.WedstrijdSessie })'"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h3>@Model.PanelName</h3>

        <div class="container-fluid mb-3">
            <div class="container bg-light">
                @foreach (var panel in Model.PanelComposition)
                {
                    <hr style="border-style: dotted;"/>

                    <div class="row formgroup align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label class="control-label"><p class="font-weight-bold">@panel.Functie:</p></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <select asp-for="@panel.FK_Jury"
                                    asp-items="Model.JuryMembers"
                                    class="form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                                    id ="currentSelectedJuryMemmber"
                                    name="currentSelectedJuryMemmber" 
                                    value="@panel.JuryName"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="@panel.JuryName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**_EditPanelView.cshtml** displays a combo box for each duty, which contains a listing of the available jury members. In the end, we can click on "Edit" which then changes the listing. But no matter what I do the PanelComposition property always comes back as null, while it's supposed to contain the Jurymember data. How do I fix this?

**EDIT**

Based on an answer I got I reworked the code in **_EditPanelView.cshtml** like this:

```
<form asp-action="SavePanel" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="currentPanel" name="currentPanel" asp-for="@Model.PanelName" />
    <input type="hidden" id="wedstrijdSessie" name="wedstrijdSessie" asp-for="@Model.WedstrijdSessie" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Aanpassen" class="btn btn-outline-info" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <input type="button" value="Terug naar het overzicht" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "JuryOpsteller", new { id = Model.WedstrijdSessie })'" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3>@Model.PanelName</h3>

    <div class="container-fluid mb-3">
        <div class="container bg-light">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.PanelComposition.Count; i++)
            {
                <hr style="border-style: dotted;" />

                <div class="row formgroup align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label class="control-label"><p class="font-weight-bold">@Model.PanelComposition[i].Functie:</p></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <select asp-items="@Model.JuryMembers"
                                class="form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                                name="@Model.PanelComposition[i].JuryName"
                                value="@Model.PanelComposition[i].FK_Jury">
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PanelComposition[i].JuryName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This fixed one issue, as the poster suggested this allowed the model to be mapped and for the HttpPost action to load the data.

However, I still have a couple of issues as you can see on the following screenshot:

[image]

As you can see the combo boxes all showed the same option, the 1st loaded record as you can see within the generated HTML:

[image]

It seems that the data gets into the HTML, but the tag still has some problems.

Anyone here has an idea? I've added the data which is loaded into the used model as [json file](http://www.cdandp.be/stackoverflow/jurytool/data.json) (long live NewtonSoft).

Comment: Can you show the model `PanelOverviewModel`?

Comment: public class PanelOverviewModel
    {
        #region Properties
        public int WedstrijdSessie { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, PanelModel> PanelComposition { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, List<string>> PanelMatrix;
        public string SelectedPanel { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing myself on the replies I got, I managed to get it working by combining a couple of responses and a little bit of logical thinking.

The current code allows me to get the combo boxes generated correctly, and read the changed values in a post:

```
<form asp-action="SavePanel" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="currentPanel" name="currentPanel" asp-for="@Model.PanelName" />
    <input type="hidden" id="wedstrijdSessie" name="wedstrijdSessie" asp-for="@Model.WedstrijdSessie" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Aanpassen" class="btn btn-outline-info" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <input type="button" value="Terug naar het overzicht" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "JuryOpsteller", new { id = Model.WedstrijdSessie })'" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3>@Model.PanelName</h3>

    <div class="container-fluid mb-3">
        <div class="container bg-light">
            @for(var i = 0; i < Model.PanelComposition.Count; i++)
            {
                int juryCount = i;
                <hr style="border-style: dotted;" />

                <div class="row formgroup align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label class="control-label"><p class="font-weight-bold">@Model.PanelComposition[i].Functie:</p></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-8">
                        <select asp-for= "PanelComposition[juryCount].FK_Jury"
                                asp-items = "Model.JuryMembers"
                                class="form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                                name="PanelComposition[@juryCount].FK_Jury"
                                value="@Model.PanelComposition[juryCount].FK_Jury.ToString()">
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PanelComposition[i].JuryName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This generates the form the way I need it:

[image: The form]

When testing I found the model mapping now works properly, so I get the updated data I need:

```
{
  "WedstrijdSessie": 5828,
  "PanelName": null,
  "ClubName": null,
  "PanelComposition": [
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 156,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 66,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 143,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 121,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 110,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 129,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 46,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 64,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 64,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 64,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    },
    {
      "FK_WedstrijdSessie": null,
      "SK_JuryOpgave": null,
      "FK_Jury": 88,
      "Omschrijving": null,
      "Functie": null,
      "Naam": null,
      "Voornaam": null,
      "JuryNiveau": null,
      "JuryNiveauNr": null,
      "SK_Club": null,
      "Club": null,
      "Vlg_PositieToegekend": null,
      "JuryName": " "
    }
  ],
  "JuryMembers": null
}
```

With this, I can continue, though I wonder about 1 thing. As you can see the data I obtain in the post-action only contains a value for **FK_Jury**. Is there a way to also have the value for **Functie** filled in?

Answer (score 1):

According to this code, `PanelComposition` is a collection. In the form, its name should be changed to a type of collection.

Remove `<input type="hidden" id="currentMembers" name="currentMembers" asp-for="@Model.PanelComposition" />`.

Change the code (foreach) in **_EditPanelView.cshtml**.

In tag `<select>`, add `name="PanelComposition[@i].FK_Jury"`.

```
  @for(var i=0;i<Model.PanelComposition.Count;i++)
            {
                <hr style="border-style: dotted;" />

                <div class="row formgroup align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label class="control-label"><p class="font-weight-bold">@Model.PanelComposition[i].Functie:</p></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <select 
                                asp-items="Model.JuryMembers"
                                class="form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                                name="PanelComposition[@i].FK_Jury"
                                value="@Model.PanelComposition[i].JuryName"></select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PanelComposition[i].JuryName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Then, this form can map the model.

[image]

Dynamically change the selected state.

```
<select asp-items="Model.JuryMembers.Where(x=>x.Text==Model.PanelComposition[i].JuryName?x.Selected=true:x.Selected=false)"
                                class="form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                                name="PanelComposition[@i].FK_Jury"
                                value="@Model.PanelComposition[i].JuryName"></select>
```

Comment: Thx, it works! But why does it work now? Perhaps anyone here can share some light on it?

Comment: Because the mapping of the collection requires sequential values to map.

Comment: It seems I was a bit too fast. See my description for an explanation

Comment: `name="PanelComposition[@i].FK_JuryName"` should be added in a input text. And change the attribute `name` in `<select name='PanelComposition[@i].FK_Jury'>`

Comment: I'm affraid I don't directly understand what you mean.

Comment: You can edit the selected status through `asp-items`.

Comment: OK. But then 1 only get 1 option. I should get a list of options with the currently selected user highlighted as its current choice.

Comment: Enoding it like this did the trick

<select asp-for= "PanelComposition[juryCount].FK_Jury"
        asp-items = "Model.JuryMembers"
        class="form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
        name="PanelComposition[@juryCount].FK_Jury"
        value="@Model.PanelComposition[juryCount].FK_Jury.ToString()">
</select>